# How to work with bucklescript requires and google functions

Tags: require, gcloud, bucklescript

I'm trying to deploy functions created with bucklescript to [google functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) but the deploy won't run without this error :

> Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?
>   Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'bs-platform/lib/js/js_json.js'

I'm using the `gcloud beta functions deploy` utility. My code is using the `Js.Json` module, which produce `var Js_json = require("bs-platform/lib/js/js_json.js");` in the outputed js code. My `package.json` contains the `bs-platform` package.

Is there a way to setup bucklescript or the gcloud utility to make my code acceptable?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `gcloud`, but you might have to use a bundler like webpack or rollup to bundle it up into a single file. The `require` call is standard commonjs, nothing bucklescript-specific.

Comment: You can also configure `bsb` to emit es6 or amdjs instead of commonjs modules, if that works better.

Comment: @glennsl in the end I used rollup to bundle deps and it did the trick. If you wish you can give an answer and I'll be able to approve it.

Comment: Done. Thanks for coming back to confirm that it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BuckleScript's `require`s are just standard CommonJS `require`s, and can be bundled up into a single file using a bundler like webpack. You can also configure `bsb` to emit es6 modules (see the `package-specs` property of the [`bsconfig.json` schema](https://bucklescript.github.io/bucklescript/docson/#build-schema.json)) and bundle them up using rollup.